# Dealing with very similar objects

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

This is not specific to any language, but I'm working with javascript so I'll use javascript.

I have a "class" `SimpleObject`, and another class `CompoundObject`. They have the similar functionality and almost similar interfaces. Take the following example (simplified and irrelevant stuff removed):

**SimpleObject:**

This is just a base class, and `init` is overridden on child classes to provide other functionalities

```
function SimpleObject(data){
    this.data = data;
    this.init();
}

SimpleObject.prototype = {
    init: function(){
        // Irrelevant data processing code here
    },
    getData: function(){
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

**CompoundObject:**

`CompoundObject` is made up of different kinds of `SimpleObject`. The simple objects interact with each other, and the compound object handles that internally.

```
function CompoundObject(simpleObjectsArray, data){
    this.simpleObjectsArray = simpleObjectsArray;

    this.init(data);
}

CompoundObject.prototype = {
    init: function(data){
        // Irrelevant data processing code here
    },
    getData: function(){
        var array = [], i;

        for(i = 0; i < this.simpleObjectsArray.length; i++){
            array[array.length] = {
                simpleObjectType: // some value here,
                data: this.simpleObjectsArray[i].getData();
            };
        }
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

As you can see, they have similar structure, and kind of a similar return type for `getData`, the only difference is `SimpleObject` only returns the data, while `CompoundObject` returns the data + some other properties of each internal  `SimpleObject`.

Now, the value of `getData` is going to be used in a lot of other classes, mostly UIs. Since they are similar, the UIs(or rather, the visuals) for them are very similar. The problem is they are similar enough to use the same visuals, but different enough to warrant different classes to handle them. I want to design them so they can just use the same UI class, but maintain decoupling.

Pardon me if the question might be a bit confusing, as I myself is confused too.

Comment: Have a look at the composite design pattern.

Comment: What I'm using is a semi-composite pattern. Because the `CompoundObject`'s getters must return a different type (it lists the data and from which simpleobject it came from. So in essence the `CompoundObject` is more of a container than a composite.